# What is the best way to initialize a pointer to a char array as mutable?

Tags: c, arrays, char

It is clear that initializing a char array like

```
char* string = "foobar";
```

will make it immutable.  On the other hand, initializing a char array like

```
char string[] = "foobar";
```

will be make it mutable.

What is the best way to make a mutable initialization of pointer to a char array?

```
// member char arrays are immutable
char* arr[] = {"foo", "bar"};
```

Comment: Slight correction: it's immutable on *all systems*. Some systems just fail to trap the undefined behavior and crash, but even worse things can happen if they don't: for example, two string literals that have the same contents, or where one is the tail of the other, can share the same memory, so that attempting to modify one causes your program to see the modification in the other!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have C99 features at your disposal, compound literals do the trick:

```
char *arr[] = { (char[]){"foo"}, (char[]){"bar"} };
```

Answer (score 0):

One options is to guess the maximum size of the strings in the array, and use:

```
char arr[][SIZE] = {"foo", "bar"};
```

where `SIZE` is to be replaced by a number.

```
char arr[][4] = {"foo", "bar"};
```

would work given the strings but it won't if you use:

```
char arr[][4] = {"foo", "fubar"};
```

When such a line is compiled, gcc prints the following warning:

> warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [enabled by default]
>       char arr[][4] = {"foo", "fubar"};

If you are using a different compiler, it might not complain. Just be aware.